# Get appointments for all rooms

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

currently, I can get all appointments for one room, but I have many rooms, if I want to show all appointments, the performance is very bad, so I want to ask if has method to Get all appointments for multiple rooms one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no operation to do that. However you can use the GetUserAvailbility operation that will give you the FreeBusy status and a subset of the Calendar property Start,End,Location,Subject  if you request the CalendarDetails see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532567%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx . There are some limitations around this operation generally the Time window in 42 days and you can only retrieve a max of 100 Mailboxes per request.

Cheers
Glen

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495614(v=exchg.150).aspx

```
// Initialize values for the start and end times, and the number of appointments to retrieve.
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(30);
        const int NUM_APPTS = 5;

        // Initialize the calendar folder object with only the folder ID. 
        CalendarFolder calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new PropertySet());

        // Set the start and end time and number of appointments to retrieve.
        CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate, NUM_APPTS);

        // Limit the properties returned to the appointment's subject, start time, and end time.
        cView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Subject, AppointmentSchema.Start, AppointmentSchema.End);

        // Retrieve a collection of appointments by using the calendar view.
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = calendar.FindAppointments(cView);

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe first " + NUM_APPTS + " appointments on your calendar from " + startDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + 
                          " to " + endDate.Date.ToShortDateString() + " are: \n");

        foreach (Appointment a in appointments)
        {
            Console.Write("Subject: " + a.Subject.ToString() + " ");
            Console.Write("Start: " + a.Start.ToString() + " ");
            Console.Write("End: " + a.End.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```